# custom less not working in magento 2 production mode

Tags: magento2, css, frontend, less, ui

I've a less file inside app/design/frontend//web/css/source/_test.less and included in default.xml like

```
<head>
    <css src="css/source/_test.css" />
</head>
```

It's working perfectly in developer mode but in production mode it's showing error like "

(index):1 Refused to apply style from ....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add your custom CSS you just have to declare it in that your theme layout.

**XML path:**

> app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Less path:**

> app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/web/css/custom.less

Comment: like that only i've created. in production  mode it's not working

Comment: please update your LESS
_test.less to test.less & _test.css to test.css